# Dirac fermion in curved space

Tags: dirac-equation, topological-insulators

What is the connection between Dirac equation in curved space-time and effective Hamiltonian for Dirac fermion in curved space (topological insulators)?

I am trying to find this connection but I am stuck a little. I tryed to do this for cylinder - just changing the metric $$ds^2 = c^2dt^2 - dx^2 - dy^2 - dz^2$$ to $$ds^2 = c^2dt^2 - dr^2 - r^2d\phi^2-dz^2$$
deriving Dirac equation (e.g. [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_equation_in_curved_spacetime)) in this geometry and then taking $r = const.$ Unfortunatelly, there is no angle dependence in my equations, but people who do this have $sin$ and $cos$ e.g. [Zhang](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0904.0690.pdf), [Rosenberg](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1002.3155v1.pdf), [Zhang](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1005.3542v1.pdf) as effective hamiltonian. 
Could You please help me?

In deriving the Dirac equation I used the folowing tetrad:
$e_{r}^{2} = 1$, $e_{r}^{3}=0$, $e_{\phi}^{2} = 0$, $e_{\phi}^{3}=r$. What about this choice:

$e_{r}^{2} = \cos\phi$, $e_{r}^{3}=\sin\phi$, $e_{\phi}^{2} = -r\sin\phi$, $e_{\phi}^{3}=r\cos\phi$.

I will get the same result at the end or different? Tetrads are not unigue I guess? How to choose them correctly?

Comment: Related question by OP: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/130841/2451 (link only visible for 10k users.)

Comment: You have an example, in the formulae $(35) \to (40)$, page $13$ in this [paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1003.5179)

Comment: @Nex_Friedrich You're right! there isn't a single choice of tetrads for a given metric. Count: metric is symmetric so they have $D(D+1)/2$ components, while the vielbein has no constraint and have $D^2$ components.

Comment: Am I missing something? I want my Dirac fermion to live on a surface of a cylindrical wire, should I use the second vierbein? How to construct them if I have some manifold?